# How to create a thread in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I need help in creating a thread, C# winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Thread t=new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start)).Start();
}

public void Start() {
    MessageBox.Show("Thread Running");
}
```

I keep getting this message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Thread
```

what to do the msdn documentation is no good

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would work:

```
Thread t = new Thread (new ThreadStart (Start));
t.Start();
```

And this would work as well:

```
new Thread (new ThreadStart(Start)).Start();
```

The MSDN documentation is good and correct, but you're doing it wrong. :)
You do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread (new ThreadStart(Start)).Start();
```

So, what you do here in fact, is try to assign the object that is returned by the Start() method (which is void) to a Thread object; hence the error message.

Comment: In particular, the MSDN documentation indicates that the return type of `Start()` is void...

Answer (score 4):

The .NET framework also provides a handy thread class [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It is nice because you can add it using the VisualEditor and setup all of it's properties.

Here is a nice small tutorial (with images) on how to use the backgroundworker: 
http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: I'd have to second that suggestion. The BackgroundWorker approach is much more beginner friendly than using Thread. It also helps you marshal data between the UI thread and the worker thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting it up as such:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // create instance of thread, and store it in the t-variable:
  Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
  // start the thread using the t-variable:
  t.Start();
}
```

The `Thread.Start`-method returns `void` (i.e. nothing), so when you write

```
Thread t = something.Start();
```

you are trying to set the result of the `Start`-method, which is void, to the `t`-variable. This is not possible, and so you have to split the statement into two lines as specified above.