# Why does my windows form not load? Is it just my build or does this truly not pop anything up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code along with other methods after it, but cannot get the form I've been using in designer to pop up. The only thing that pops up successfully is the MessageBox asking the player if they would like to play as X. I've tried commenting that out to see if that's the issue for why it won't load, but I'm completely lost as to why my form will not load at all.

```
    namespace mmelichar_Topic6_Activity13
{
    public partial class mmelichar_TicTacToe : Form
    {
        int player = 0;
        int position;
        int turn = 0;
        int playerMove;
        int firstMove;
        int secondMove;
        string[,] location = new string[3, 3] { { "", "", "" }, { "", "", "" }, { "", "", "" } };

        public mmelichar_TicTacToe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mmelichar_TicTacToe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //There's only two moves that have to be hard-coded for AI to be able to
            //play tic-tac-toe near perfectly, each game /should/ result in a tie or
            //a win for the CPU. Other than that, the tryWin and tryBlock methods
            //should be able to win the game if there is an availability for that,
            //or block the opponent from winning if they cannot win quite yet.
            Random rnd = new Random();



            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to play as X?", "Player Choice", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                player = 1;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                player = 0;
            }
            //player is O
            if (player == 0 && turn == 0)
            {
                firstTurnCPU();
                //player turn
                mre.WaitOne();
            }
            //player is X
            if (player == 1 && turn == 0)
            {
                //player turn 1
                mre.WaitOne();

                //cpu turn 1
                firstTurnCPU();

                //player turn 2
                mre.WaitOne();

                //cpu turn 2
                secondTurnCPU();

                //player turn 3
                mre.WaitOne();

                //cpu turn 3
                tryWin();
                tryBlock();

                //player turn 4
                mre.WaitOne();

                //cpu turn 4
                tryWin();
                tryBlock();

                //player turn 

            }
        }
    private readonly ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void playerTurn_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mre.Set();
    }
```

edit: updated code to remove while loop and include my ManualResetEvent

Comment: Check what is inside the `InitializeComponent()` method to see if there is anything else which should be loaded.

Comment: What you have looks like an infinite loop on the UI thread, which would certainly prevent the UI from rendering.  Do you really need to constantly loop, or if this is a Windows Forms app could you instead have the game respond to UI events?

Comment: I definitely could remove the while loop, since I actually did handle this later by checking for a win. I'll do that. Also going to check what's inside my InitializeComponent() method just in case something funky got in there.

Comment: This looks like a console-like program you tried to port to Windows.  Different environments.  Get rid of the while-loop entirely.

Comment: InitializeComponent hasn't been touched, and removing the while loop didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm thinking the `private readonly ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);` and `//player turn 1
                mre.WaitOne();` could cause my form to not load because I'm not allowing it to take an action after the player has been selected, but if this is the case, I'm not entirely certain how to wrestle control from the user to not allow input during the computer's turn, or if I even need to given that the computer will be making decisions faster than a user can click multiple buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while (playing)
{
    // perform a bunch of logic
    // but probably don't do anything async or properly interact with the UI
}
```

An infinite loop on the UI threat would certainly prevent the UI from ever drawing to the screen.  (It may also be running away with the CPU a lot more than you want it to.)

If you really do want a "game loop" style of game construction, there [are approaches you can take](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67651) in Windows Forms.  But now would be a good time to really think through the design of the game before going that route.

Windows Forms is highly event-driven.  It's idle most of the time, and responds when users interact with the UI.  (A click here, a mouse-over there, etc.)  If your game fits that structure (turn based, etc.) then use that structure since it's more native to Windows Forms.

You can also combine the two, using Windows Forms events to process user interactions, but when the program launches you can [create a *separate thread*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1310381/328193) for your game loop to process ongoing events/logic in the background.  Just make sure that loop isn't killing the CPU by constantly running.  It's reasonable to sleep the thread for a moment on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I already removed this, and it does not load still.

Comment: @bynary: You removed the loop entirely?  What's the updated code?

Comment: Edited initial post to reflect changes and my concerns of my ManualResetEvent being the cause of this, since I was using it to try to wait for a player turn. If this is the case of why I cannot load the form, I just need to be able to wait for a user input without using MRE, which I'm unsure of how to do.

Comment: @bynary: A `ManualResetEvent` can definitely do this as well.  You're basically telling the entire application "Don't do anything yet", which is why it's not doing anything.  Start with something simpler.  Don't mess with threads yet until you have to, which you entirely may not need to do.  Just start with a form that has the game inputs you want, and handle the events of the user interacting with that form.  You don't have to "wait" for user input, the application is generally idle and is already waiting for input events.

Comment: I guess I'm just overthinking the whole  thing, and just need to throw an event into the button click method I have to make it start the next computer turn.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems within my code:

First, an infinite while loop that I forgot to remove, increasing CPU usage needlessly.

Second, use of ManualResetEvent instead of just using normal flow within the program to hand control back and forth from player to CPU and vice-versa.